# Incorrectly working animation-play-state on Safari

Tags: html, css, animation, safari

during the development of the slider on css, the following problem occurred. Incorrectly performs the animation-playstate property. The bottom line is that when you move the cursor over the slide, the animation should be a paused. And after the mouse left the animation, it should continue from the current position.

codepen: https://codepen.io/Andrey_07/pen/bxyExZ

```
.clients-grid__column {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 50%;
/* width: 160px;*/
width: 300px;
min-width: 300px;
margin-left: -160px;
transform-origin: center;
animation: columns-trajectory-1800 80s infinite;
animation-timing-function: linear;
will-change: transform;
animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-moz-animation-play-state: running;
-o-animation-play-state: running;
-ms-animation-play-state: running;
```

}

```
.clients-grid__inner.stop .clients-grid__column {
animation-play-state: paused;
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
-moz-animation-play-state: paused;
-o-animation-play-state: paused;
-ms-animation-play-state: paused;
```

}

Comment: Can you please post a fiddle demo example here?

Comment: @VikasJadhav Here https://codepen.io/Andrey_07/pen/bxyExZ

Comment: Couldn't reproduce In Safari 11.0 macOS

Comment: @VikasJadhav it's strange, working for me